# Using PHP 5.5* on Mac Os X 10.10.3 (Yosemite)

Tags: php, macos

I am trying to get my local Mac machine to use the 5.5 version of PHP.  I have run the command:

```
curl -s http://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 5.5
```

and get the output:

```
****
[WARNING]
Detected OS X Yosemite 10.10. As this is quite new, there may be issues still. Your mileage may vary.
****
Get packager.tgz
Unpack packager.tgz
Please type in your password, as we want to install this into /usr/local
Start packager (may take some time)
downloading http://php-osx.liip.ch/install/5.5-10.10-frontenddev-latest.dat
downloading http://php-osx.liip.ch/install/5.5-10.10/frontenddev/5.5-10.10-frontenddev-5.5.25-20150515-095348.tar.bz2

Installing package 5.5-10.10-frontenddev into root /
Package 5.5-10.10-frontenddev is already installed at version 5.5.25-20150515-095348. You wanted to install version 5.5.25-20150515-095348.
```

I removed the comment on the line for PHP at the root in my httpd.conf file (`LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so`), however, when I return to my console and type php -v I get:

```
*******:~ ************$ php -v
PHP 5.4.10 (cli) (built: Jan 21 2013 15:12:32) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

It is still PHP version 5.4 being used.  What can I do to get the system to use PHP 5.5?  Thank you!

Comment: use `brew` to install php55. The installer will place the required binaries, libraries, and configurations under the `/usr/local` directory tree.  /usr/local/bin should come before /usr/bin in the path, and voila.

Comment: Yosemite has `PHP 5.5` already installed;  I'm scratching my head on how you ended up with `PHP 5.4`.

Comment: @YvesLeBorge: how do I install it with brew?